# Should [gerrymandering] be made a synonym of [redistricting]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering), gerrymandering is the:

> practice intended to establish an arguably unfair political advantage for a particular party or group by manipulating the boundaries of electoral districts, which is most commonly used in first-past-the-post electoral systems.

According to Wikipedia's page on [Redistricting in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redistricting_in_the_United_States):

> Redistricting in the United States is the process of drawing electoral district boundaries. A congressional act enacted in 1967 requires that representatives be elected from single-member districts.

Should the tag [gerrymandering](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerrymandering) (43 questions) therefore be made a synonym of [redistricting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redistricting) (16 questions)?

Comment: There's redistricting outside the US, even if Wikipedia doesn't have an article on the topic in general. Wikipedia does have such articles, but they're not so easy to find e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_commissions_(United_Kingdom) Also it seems the preferred UK term is "redistribution" https://aceproject.org/ace-en/topics/bd/annex/bdy/bdy_gb

Comment: However some academic works on the UK use the "redistricting" terminology https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/british-journal-of-political-science/article/abs/estimating-the-partisan-impact-of-redistricting-in-great-britain/6B7F32DD50A817FBDDC79532BD88EC56 ; https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/153244000400400407?journalCode=spaa

Comment: @Fizz and [there has been gerrymandering in other countries too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering#Examples). Of course they may call it differently. Any place that does redistricting with a FPTP system has the potential for gerrymandering (drawing districts to benefit some political party in elections), I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say no.

This isn't a site purely about US politics, and many other countries have mechanisms in place to try and ensure fair creation of election districts (terminology may vary from place to place). As such, there are plenty of questions that might reasonably be asked about redistricting that have nothing to do with gerrymandering.

Gerrymandering is the abuse of the redistricting system to create an advantage, and is illegal in many places.  It just happens to be the norm in the US system. But to me, merging the tags would be like arguing that 'business' and 'fraud' tags should be merged.

Comment: While I agree with your points, I'm not sure if that's an argument against grouping those questions together through a tag. For example, the earliest two tag synonyms on our site map both [left] and [right] to [ideology], not because they are the same, but because categorizing them together helps grouping highly related questions by the same keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no because of the nature of gerrymandering makes it something that it would be good to have a tag to clarify it is about that specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue in favor of making them synonyms because it is in the eye of the beholder which is which. The ones doing the gerrymandering probably call it redistricting while those who oppose the outcome of gerrymandered districts call it gerrymandering. Rules to prevent gerrymandering explicitly are also rules on redistricting so there seems to be a lot of overlap.

I would choose [redistricting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redistricting) as the main tag because it doesn't pass judgement. If a question wishes to make the point that something is about gerrymandering explicitly then they can express that in the question body.

Comment: There are [seven questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redistricting+gerrymandering) that use both [gerrymandering] and [redistricting] tags. When thinking about those questions, I asked myself (of the poster), "Which one are you asking about, gerrymandering or redistricting?" But I also note that more than half the questions tagged [gerrymandering] also use "gerrymandering" or "gerrymander" in the title and seven don't use either word in the question. Further evaluation may be in order.

Comment: @RickSmith Well I think using the term in the title isn't always what they should be doing

Comment: I reviewed 66 questions with the tags [voting-districts] or [redistricting] or [gerrymandering], they are related. Changes will be made to 49 questions. Most changes will be adding [voting-districts]. Second is removing [gerrymandering]. I will be making those changes occasionally.